# Why i can't add Cron entry to my ubuntu 18.04 server?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cron, zsh, ubuntu-18.04

Created *laravel* artisan Command to execute inside *Laravel 5.5 Scheduler* (every month).

When i add Cron entry to my ubuntu 18.04 server with crontab -e :

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html_public/project-name/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

[command on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lBjH.png)

**Note:**

```
$ php artisan schedule:run
```

Work just fine

[Documentation used](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction)

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/task-scheduling-no-command-app-found-but-there-are-16-similar-ones

Comment: Maybe try to write your cron in the other way: `* * * * * cd /var/www/public_html/laravel-project-name && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Great! If yes, it would be nice if you can accept my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write your cron in the other way:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/public_html/laravel-project-name && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```